# \multirow - Long name breaking/ruining layout

Tags: tables, multirow

When I use this `tabular` enviroinment, for some reason the second-lowest row gets messed up badly. Can anybody please tell me how to fix this?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, fleqn, parskip]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
    $[a, b] := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a \leq x \leq b\}$ & kompaktes Intervall \\ \hline
    $(a, b) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a < x < b\}$ & offenes, beschr"anktes Intervall \\ \hline
    $[a, b) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a \leq x < b\}$ & \multirow{2}{*}{halboffenes, beschr"anktes Intervall} \\
    $(a, b] := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a < x \leq b\}$ \\ \hline
    $[a, \infty) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a \leq x\}$ \\ \multirow{2}{*}{abgeschlossenes, unbeschr"anktes Intervall} \\
    $(-\infty, b] := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x \leq b\}$ \\ \hline
    $(a, \infty) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a < x\}$ & \multirow{2}{*}{offenes, unbeschr"anktes Intervall} \\
    $(-\infty, b) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x < b\}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You missed some `ampersand`s (`&`) below the row that contains `multirow` command:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, fleqn, parskip]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
    $[a, b] := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a \leq x \leq b\}$ & kompaktes Intervall \\ \hline
    $(a, b) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a < x < b\}$ & offenes, beschr"anktes Intervall \\ \hline
    $[a, b) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a \leq x < b\}$ & \multirow{2}{*}{halboffenes, beschr"anktes Intervall} \\
    $(a, b] := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a < x \leq b\}$ & \\ \hline  %%<<<here
    $[a, \infty) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a \leq x\}$ & \multirow{2}{*}{abgeschlossenes, unbeschr"anktes Intervall}  \\
    $(-\infty, b] := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x \leq b\}$ & \\ \hline %%<<< here
    $(a, \infty) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a < x\}$ & \multirow{2}{*}{offenes, unbeschr"anktes Intervall} \\
    $(-\infty, b) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x < b\}$ & \\ \hline %%%<<<<<here
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your table you have some errors resulting in the bad looking of your table. 
I suggest you write always the ampersands in the same column as I did. So you find easier missing ampersands in your table. Don't forget to write all necceccary `&` for your table, even if an empty cell is following.

Package `a4wide` is outdated, please do not use it longer. See `l2tabu.pdf` (`texdoc l2tabu`) for more information.

You will get better looking tables without lines, have a look into package `booktabs` and its manual (`texdoc booktabs`).

Corrected and pretty printed MWE:

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83415/multirow-long-name-breaking-ruining-layout
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, fleqn, parskip]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % original: utf8x
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
%\usepackage{a4wide}         % outdated, see l2tabu.pdf
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
  $[a, b] := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a \leq x \leq b\}$ & kompaktes Intervall              \\ \hline
  $(a, b) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a < x < b\}$       & offenes, beschränktes Intervall  \\ \hline
  $[a, b) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a \leq x < b\}$    & \multirow{2}{*}{halboffenes, beschränktes Intervall} \\
  $(a, b] := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a < x \leq b\}$    &                                  \\ \hline
  $[a, \infty) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a \leq x\}$   & \multirow{2}{*}{abgeschlossenes, unbeschränktes Intervall} \\
  $(-\infty, b] := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x \leq b\}$  &                                  \\ \hline
  $(a, \infty) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: a < x\}$      & \multirow{2}{*}{offenes, unbeschränktes Intervall} \\
  $(-\infty, b) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x < b\}$     &                                  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: WOHEY :D
Thanks to all contributors for the promt reply, you really helped me out :)